# Pygame crashes every time i click in the window

Tags: python, pygame

Here is the code:

```
import pygame, time

pygame.init()

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,155,0)
blue = (0,0,255)

def button(x,y,w,h,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        if click [0] == 1 and action != None:
            if action == "exit":
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

gameExit = False
menu1 = True
menu2 = True
gameloop = True

while not gameExit:   
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True

    while menu1:
        logo1 = pygame.image.load('logo.jpg')
        gameDisplay.blit(logo1, (1, 1))
        time.sleep(2)
        pygame.display.update()

        while menu2:
            logo2 = pygame.image.load("logo2.jpg")
            gameDisplay.blit(logo2, (0, 0))
            time.sleep(2)
            pygame.display.update()
            time.sleep(2)

            while gameloop:
                gameDisplay.fill(white)
                button(0, 0, 10,10,"exit")
                pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, (0, 0, 10, 10))
                pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(15)
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Im assuming its all the while loops, i wanted to create a slide show of 2 logos that plays for 2 seconds each (which works) but as soon as I get past the slideshow, I click close, and it crashes. I tried adding a quick button (red square at the top right) and it crashes aswell. I am completely stumped and have looked through everything and made a ton of changes but it crashes... Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `while` loops *are* causing your problems, because you are never breaking out of them.

Personally, I think you should use the current `pygame.time.get_ticks()` in order to time your events. Here's an example:

```
# Code above here is unchanged

gameExit = False

logo1 = pygame.image.load('logo.png')  # Don't load these in a loop!
logo2 = pygame.image.load('logo2.png') # Only need to load them once.

# Make sure you record start_time here! Because the timer actually
# started several seconds before the display is ready.

start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() / 1000

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True

    time = pygame.time.get_ticks() / 1000
    elapsed = time - start_time

    gameDisplay.fill(black)

    if elapsed > 4:
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        button(0, 0, 10, 10, 'exit')
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, (0, 0, 10, 10))
    elif elapsed > 2:
        gameDisplay.blit(logo2, (0, 0))
    elif elapsed > 0:
        gameDisplay.blit(logo1, (1, 1))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(15)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

What I did was check to see if the `elapsed` time was greater than 4 seconds. If so, show the red square. If not, we go to the next one. Is time after 2 seconds? If so, show `logo2`. Finally, if the time is `> 0`, which it is right in the beginning, we show `logo1`. They are setup in the opposite order, because of the way `if / elif` works: it only catches the first one that is `True`. So as time goes on, the higher and higher options become `True`.

Does that make sense?

Comment: You may be able to select an answer without needing to upvote, to mark the question as "answered" (green checkmark?) I'm glad it worked for you. My pleasure!